# How can I improve my Program so that eScan doesn't think it's a virus?

Tags: c#, registry, virus, virus-scanning

This is my class:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("User32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uiAction, int uiParam,
    string pvParam, uint fWinIni);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists("C:/temp"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory("C:/temp");
            }

            if (!File.Exists(@"c:\temp\image.png"))
            {
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.DownloadFile(new Uri("https://i.imgur.com/dhaP3Mu.png"), @"c:\temp\image.png");
                }
            }

            if (!CheckWallpaper(@"c:\temp\image.png"))
            {
                SystemParametersInfo(0x0014, 0, @"c:\temp\image.png", 0x0001);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    static bool CheckWallpaper(string imagePath)
    {
        bool isSame = false;

        try
        {
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop\WallPaper"))
            {
                if (key != null)
                {
                    Object o = key.GetValue(imagePath);
                    if (o != null)
                    {
                        Version version = new Version(o as String);  //"as" because it's REG_SZ...otherwise ToString() might be safe(r)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)  //just for demonstration...it's always best to handle specific exceptions
        {
            //react appropriately
        }

        return isSame;
    }
}
```

It's just a little prank, that makes the user impossible to change his wallpaper. But now I couldn't build it, cause eData instantly said that it's a virus of gen "Variant.Razy.587029". I can understand it thinks that it's a virus, so is there a way to improve my code that it doesn't look suspicious? I don't have the problem with Kaspersky. And I cannot change the virus scan settings, as it is not my pc obviously

EDIT: I'm not finished yet, for example the CheckWallpaper() always outputs `false`, I just wanted to test it.

EDIT2: I now changed the Wallpaper-check from "Looking in Registry" to "Compare `%appdata%/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Themes/TranscodedWallpaper` with my Image.png. I also added a `Thread.Sleep(1000)`, else the program gets detected again"

Comment: essentially, you are writing a virus... unless you are really really good at that, a virusscanner will always notice.

Comment: If this is a prank for a specific person you gotta prep their AV and add your program or a folder where you can run the program from to the exclusion list, then it won't be detected.

Answer (score 1):

As Glenn van Acker said, it's essentially a virus. If you really want such a program to be ignored by antiviruses, the "easiest" way is to deploy, sign and publish the program. Then write to antivirus companies to whitelist it.